# jQuery IE has gone so screwed up

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, html

I have been doing this website with a booking system, I am on a mac so i generally used Safari or Firefox... It's been coming along nicely until I chose to check it with IE.

It totally screws up the page and I haven't a clue where to start:
http://offline.raileisure.com/

Fill in the booking system on the right hand side in multiple browsers and see what the difference is... IE just doesn't like it at all.

Thanks!

Comment: He means the jQueryUI date widget on the form on the left hand side.

Comment: no i mean the pop up when you fill in the form and click get price

Comment: If he means the *left hand side*, why would he have written "the right hand side" in the question?  The date picker (on the right) works fine in IE7.

Comment: Using IE9, that whole box shows up in querks mode, but not at all on IE7 mode.  And things arn't right in IE9.  Just looking at the HTML, I think you're having most of the problems because of some bad HTML formatting, such as having a span as the container for all your divs...

Comment: Why close this? Now that the answer is known (quirks mode because of no doctype), the question should be edited, but I don't see that it should be closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your page is running in quirks mode in IE.

To prevent Quirks mode, you must add a doctype to your document. I recommend using the HTML5 doctype. Add the following to the top of your code, above your `<html>` tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Problem solved.

Quirks mode is an obsolete rendering mode that IE supports for backward compatibility with IE5.5. It really isn't necessary for any page to support it any more, so it is recommended for all sites to have a valid doctype.

You could use any of the ones listed on [this page](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) (although if your site isn't xhtml, which I don't think it is, I'd avoid the xhtml strict and transitional doctypes).

Answer (score 2):

Your page is forcing IE into Quirks Mode, which is breaking the layout/popup.

Using IE9, I put the page into IE8 Standards mode from the Developer Tools menu (F12) and it looks as you expect it to.

So, you'll want to find a way to not have your HTML trigger Quirks Mode - you should look at http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html for guidance on how to resolve the issue.